# How do I clean up white dust and spots "blooming" on rubber?

Tags: cleaning

I have a number of [designer rubber hooks (Ikea)](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60095321/) of varying colors hanging from the wall.

[image]

The black and red hooks have white spots (not pictured) all over them.

I have read that this whiteness appearing on the rubber over time is called "blooming" and is due to excess vulcanization powder coming to the surface.

I've wiped them down with olive oil, which seems to have solved it, but I don't know if this is a good solution, or a permanent solution.

**How do I clean this white bloom off the rubber and can I prevent it from happening further?**

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common solutions to rubber bloom (in pretty much any setting) is an interior car cleaner like "Armor All" (not an endorsement, just an example). This is a durable oil-based product that is less volatile and less likely to be removed by friction or otherwise.

I typically only have to re-treat the weather stripping in my car 1-2 times per year with a product like this, and it keeps them from cracking, blooming and otherwise deteriorating as fast as they might otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use silicone grease on them to prevent them from getting discolored. Silicone grease is commonly used in plumbing to lubricate gaskets, etc. It works very much like petroleum jelly in the way it forms a protective coating. But, unlike petroleum jelly, it does not harm the rubber.

For your application, it would be best to apply it very sparingly. A little goes a long way. All you need is to have a thin protective coating. After it is applied, let t sit for a few minutes and reapply if necessary. Take care to remove the excess as well.